# Python and SQLite table insert

Tags: python, sqlite

Trying to insert a value from a list into a table.

My table is called players and has only one column, username.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO players (username) VALUES (?)", name[0])
```

is what I'm trying to insert.

and I'm getting this error

```
  File "/Users/wilson/PycharmProjects/DraftPwn/Selenium.py", line 73, in getusers
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO players (username) VALUES (?)", name[0])
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`execute`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) method  takes a SQL statement, and an iterable full of parameters.

Since `name[0]` is a 6-character string, it's an iterable of 6 single-character strings. (Hence the error about 6 bindings supplied instead of 1.) Why? That's how Python works: strings are iterable. You can see this in a simple loop:

```
>>> for ch in "abc":
...     print(ch)
a
b
c
```

If you're wondering why Python was designed that way… well, have you ever written `s[0]` or `s[-3:]`? That's why.

Anyway, you don't want an iterable of 6 one-character strings, you want an iterable of one 6-character string. Like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO players (username) VALUES (?)", (name[0],))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I dont fully understand why it happens to be six one single character strings... is it my syntax or just the way my program generated name[0]?

Comment: Also, my list contains some duplicate usernames. Is there a way to get it not to crash when it is a duplicate username? I don't want my table to contain duplicates, just ignore it when a duplicate happens. Do I have to check before every insert if the username already exists?

Comment: @Wilson: For the first question, I'll update the answer. For the second, that's really a completely independent question, which should have been posted as a new question rather than tacked on as a comment to an answer on this one… but lucky for you, Bleeding Fingers answered it anyway.

Comment: @abarnert was that "if not exist" clause correct? I doubted it for table creation, that's why had it deleted.

Comment: @BleedingFingers: I don't remember what your comment was. The OP probably wants [`ON CONFLICT IGNORE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html), but without knowing exactly what he's doing and what keys he has it's hard to do more than guess. Which is exactly why it should be posted as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO players (username) VALUES (?)", (name[0],))
```

parameter should be supplied as and iterable. The `name[0]` in itself is an iterable which contains 6 elements but the statement requires 1. So put it in a `tuple` or a `list`.

From the doc:

[`execute(sql[, parameters])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)

```
# This is the qmark style:
cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))
```

Comment: Explain why this works.